# Promises + Alamofire make sure network calls always on background

Tags: swift, alamofire, promisekit

Does promises always run on background thread.

```
@IBAction func doNetworkCall(_ sender: Any) { // Does this run on 
     background thread
        Network.fetchPhotos().done { (photos) in

        }
    }

static func fetchPhotos () -> Promise<[Photo]> {
        return Promise { seal in
            AF.request("https:photosURL", method: .post, parameters: ["auth":"1231","user_id":"u12312"]).responseJSON { (response) in
                guard let data = response.data else { return }
                let coder  = JSONDecoder()
                let photos = try! coder.decode([Photo].self, from: data)
                seal.fulfill(photos)
            }
        }

    }
```

I have used promises with purpose of all network calls runs on background thread irrespective calling from main thread. I have some chain network requests which will be easier to implement.

is this assumption correct?

Answer (score 0):

Alamofire always runs its requests on a background queue. In your example the only part that isn't in the background is the `responseJSON` closure. By default that closure runs on the `.main` queue. I recommend you adopt `responseDecodable` to decode your responses so that the parsing is also in the background only call fulfill the promise in the closure. (I'm not sure whether fulfilling on the main queue is otherwise necessary.)